# Exclude value from dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to read an html table from a local file and then apply a filter to it, using python and pandas. (I'm new to pandas/python)

I'm reading the file with this code:

```
import pandas as pd

file_path = r"C:\FILE_201704.csv"
with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
    dfs = pd.read_html(f.read(),thousands='.')
print(dfs)
```

And this is the output:

```
[       COLUMN1     TOTAL
0       Value1      10000
1       Value2      11965
2       Value3      208981
3       Value4      45962
4       Value5      14568
5       Value5      05422
6       TOTAL       298034]
```

Then I try to filter the TOTAL value in "COLUMN1", but I get an error:

```
print(dfs[dfs['COLUMN1'] != 'TOTAL'])

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

How should I filter this?
Thanks!

Comment: `dfs` is a list of dataframes. Try `df = dfs[0]; df[df['Column1'] !='TOTAL']`.

Comment: Also, why do you read a `csv` file with `read_html`? Just `df = pd.read_csv(file_path)`?

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I'm using read_html because the files has an html table.. The extension is CSV, it is not a real CSV file. Can't mark your answer as correct here

Answer (score 1):

You are filtering using a string, and need to use string methods on your dataframe:

```
df[~df['COLUMN1'].str.contains('TOTAL')]
```